# Drupal insert img tag

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

How do i manage to put images inside the body in drupal,

I need  it to be like:

```
<img src="images/bg1.jpg"></img>
```

because i have this gallery where jquery takes the src from the image.
I've tried with image fields but it puts an anchor tag around it so when i click it opens the image

Hope you guys can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably just need to start your path at the sites folder.  That's where all the files that you add to the site should go.  Most of the rest is part of the core drupal package.  Once you know the path to your images folder, you can write something that looks like the path below.

```
<img src="sites/default/files/images/bg1.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to display image in body or trying to print the tag/code in the body? You can use text field with input format full HTML to if you are trying to display an image.

Comment: Yes in the full html.
But how do i get the image from the folder.
I tried base_path but it didn't work.

Comment: Or if i could remove the anchor tag from the images when i put them through image fields